# AnsiOutput color messages to Console vs File

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I'm using Spring boot with log4j2

To write colored/styled messages to console appender with Spring boot's AnsiOutput, we need to set `spring.output.ansi.enabled=ALWAYS` in intellij (My assumption is because all IDEs launch java using javaw which will not have its own console directly, so the default setting `spring.output.ansi.enabled=DETECT` will not work by default in IDEs)

But if we set this, spring boot should write the same ANSI special characters to other appenders aswell (say `File` appender) along with console as the property does not say we need to apply color formatting only to console

But, when I look at the log file, I dont see any special characters in the log messages

Can someone please explain how log4j2/spring boot is able to managed to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Boot's default configuration for Log4j2 uses different patterns for the console appender and the file appender. The pattern for the console appender is the following:

```
%clr{%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN}}}{faint} %clr{${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN}} %clr{${sys:PID}}{magenta} %clr{---}{faint} %clr{[%15.15t]}{faint} %clr{%-40.40c{1.}}{cyan} %clr{:}{faint} %m%n${sys:LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD}
```

The pattern for the file appender is the following:

```
%d{${LOG_DATEFORMAT_PATTERN}} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN} ${sys:PID} --- [%t] %-40.40c{1.} : %m%n${sys:LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD}
```

The coloring of the output is achieved using `%clr{…}{…}`. As you can see in the above, it's used in the pattern for the console appender but not in the pattern for the file appender. It's this difference that allows only the console output to be colored.

Comment: Oops. Looks like I was too dumb/dint pay enough attention to details before I posted the question. Thanks in any case